# the relation between a continuous family of distributions and a distribution of 2 variables

Tags: reference-request, generalized-functions, fa.functional-analysis, micro-local-analysis

Let X,Y be smooth manifolds and let $f:X \to C^{-\infty}(Y)$ be a continuous  map, where $ C^{-\infty}(Y)$  is the space of generalized functions on $Y$ equipped with the weak topology. By Schwartz kernel theorem, this gives us a generalized function $\xi_f$ on $X \times Y$.  Do you know any reference for this construction and its properties?

Specifically, what is the relationship  between this construction and the wave front set?  For example, if we know the  wave front set of $\xi_f$, it seems that we can bound the wave front set of $f(x)$. Is it written anywhere?

In general, it is reasonable to say that the restriction of $\xi_f$ to $\{x\}\times Y$ is $f(y)$. On the other hand there another is a notion of restriction (or more generally pull back) of a distribution (see   Hormander The analysis of Linear PD operators I, Theorem 8.2.4 ). Do you know any reference for the fact that those to notions coincide whenever both are defined?

Answer (score 1):

We have describe the constriction and its relation with WF and Hormander's restriction in section 2.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.3630.pdf